# MyBatis if clause

Tags: mybatis

I tried following if clause in MyBatis and got following exception please help me to identify the issue here..

```
public class Student{

private Integer studId;
private String name;
private String email;
private Date dob;
}
```

Mapping

```
<select id="searchStudent" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="StudentResult">
    <![CDATA[
    SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
    WHERE 1 = 1 

    <if test="studId != null">
    AND STUD_ID= #{studId}
    </if>

    <if test="name != null">
    AND NAME like #{name}
    </if>

    ]]>
</select>
```

Exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax   to use near 'test="studId != null">
    AND STUD_ID= 1
    </if>

    <if test="name != null">
    ' at line 4
### The error may exist in StudentMapper.xml
### The error may involve com.maventest.mytest.StudentMapper.searchStudent-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT * FROM STUDENTS   WHERE 1 = 1       <if test="studId != null">   AND STUD_ID= ?   </if>      <if test="name != null">   AND NAME like ?   </if>
### Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test="studId != null">
    AND STUD_ID= 1
    </if>

    <if test="name != null">
    ' at line 4
at    org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
```

Answer (score 6):

Remove `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` as this escapes all the query and mybatis doesn't process it at all so `if` is passed verbatim as part of the query to database.

```
<select id="searchStudent" parameterType="hashmap" resultMap="StudentResult">
  SELECT * FROM STUDENTS
  WHERE 1 = 1 

  <if test="studId != null">
    AND STUD_ID= #{studId}
  </if>

  <if test="name != null">
    AND NAME like #{name}
  </if>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

CDATA sections are used to escape blocks of text containing characters that would otherwise be regarded as markup [ORACLE definition].

Sometimes, we need it, specially when we have a where condition with such markups : <, > , <> , etc.

```
<![CDATA[ SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE 1 = 1 ]]>
<if test="studId != null">
<![CDATA[ AND STUD_ID= #{studId} ]]>
</if>

<if test="name != null">
**<![CDATA[ AND COD_PER <> 'ASSU' ]]>**
</if>
```

Add it just on the line with the markup problem also works.